# Derivation of ELPD from KL Divergence

Tags: probability, bayesian, mathematical-statistics, kullback-leibler

I am currently learning about how to estimate the predictive accuracy of (bayesian) models. See here: https://bebi103b.github.io/lessons/18/model_comparison.html#id4

I need help regarding the last step of the derivation. How do we get the sum of integrals from the integral of sums?

[image]

Comment: Where could I read up on that? Also, we are not only changing summation and integral, the integral is different, dyi instead of dy.

Comment: Ah. Yes. The suffix also changed. Let me dig that.

Comment: The reason it changes is because all the terms in the multivariate integral other than $\tilde{y}_i$ are irrelevant to the log term involving $\tilde{y}_i$, so integrate to 1, and consequently can be ignored.

Comment: Could you elaborate @jbowman, I only understand it until:

$$
\begin{aligned}
=& \int_y f_t(\tilde{y}) \sum_{i=1}^N log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y} \\
=& \int_y \sum_{i=1}^N f_t(\tilde{y}) log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^N \int_y f_t(\tilde{y}) log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^N \int \int ... \int \prod_{i=1}^N f_t(\tilde{y_i}) log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y_1} d\tilde{y_2} ... d\tilde{y_N}\\
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: Your indices are off; the last line has both indices $i$, but one should be, for example, $j$, and that may clarify things.  For example, make $f_t(\tilde{y}_i)$ into $f_t(\tilde{y}_j)$ (and the associated product) and you will see that only when $j=i$ does the integral equal anything but one.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @jbowman! I think I understand it now:

So for any model $M$ which we want to assess, we have to compute
$$
\int f_t(\tilde{y}) \log f_{M}(\tilde{y} \mid y) d\tilde{y}
$$
Above $y$ denotes the sample used to fit the model, whereas $\tilde{y}$ denotes the sample of size $N$ used to test the fitted model. Here, we assume that each observation $\{\tilde{y}\}_{i=1}^N$ is indepent. Thus we get
$$
\log f_M(\tilde{y} \mid y) = \sum_{i=1}^N \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y)
$$
Inserting in the equation above yields
$$
\int f_t(\tilde{y}) \sum_{i=1}^N \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y}
$$
Now using the sum rule of integration we obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \sum_{i=1}^N f_t(\tilde{y}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^N \int f_t(\tilde{y}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y} \\
\end{aligned}
$$
Factorizing $f_t(\tilde{y})$ and writing out the multidimensional integration yields
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \sum_{i=1}^N \int \prod_{j=1}^N f_t(\tilde{y_j}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y} \\
=& \sum_{i=1}^N \int \int \cdots \int f_t(\tilde{y_1}) f_t(\tilde{y_2}) \cdots f_t(\tilde{y_N}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y_1} d\tilde{y_2} \cdots d\tilde{y_N}
\end{aligned}
$$
Now only looking at $i=1$, we change the order of integration to obtain
$$
\begin{aligned}
& \int \int \cdots \int f_t(\tilde{y_1}) f_t(\tilde{y_2}) \cdots f_t(\tilde{y_N}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_1} \mid y) d\tilde{y_1} d\tilde{y_2} \cdots d\tilde{y_N} \\
=& \int f_t(\tilde{y_1}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_1} \mid y) \int f_t(\tilde{y_2}) \cdots \int f_t(\tilde{y_N}) d\tilde{y_N} \cdots d\tilde{y_2} d\tilde{y_1} 
\end{aligned}
$$
Note that all integrals for $j \neq 1$ evaluate to $1$, thus we get
$$
= \int f_t(\tilde{y_1}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_1} \mid y) d\tilde{y_1} 
$$
More generally all integrals for $j \neq i$ evaluate 1, so the above equation leads to
$$
\sum_{i=1}^N \int f_t(\tilde{y_i}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y_i}
$$
And this formula is known as the **expected log pointwise predictive density** (elpd, aka elppd)
$$
\boxed{
\text{elpd} = \sum_{i=1}^N \int f_t(\tilde{y_i}) \log f_M(\tilde{y_i} \mid y) d\tilde{y_i}
}
$$